# I want to sort the sheet according to the rule

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl

I have a list:

```
std::list<std::string> list = {data2, data2, data2, data3, data3, data1, data1};
```

I have a sorting rule:

```
std::list<std::string> sortRule = {data1, data2, data3};
```

I need to sort the `list` according to `sortRule`, i.e. that was:

```
list = {data1, data1, data2, data2, data2, data3, data3};
```

As I understand it, I need to use `std::list::sort` and lambda function..

Comment: did you try something? Its just sort with a custom predicate based on the index in `sortRule`

Comment: Bad news: you cannot use `std::sort` with a `std::list`, no matter how you go about it. `std::sort` does not work with a `std::list`. You will need to rethink your entire approach, from the ground up.

Comment: there is `std::list::sort` that takes a custom comparator. I don't see how that is fundamentally different than using `std::sort`. Implentation wise it is different and it has different complexity guarantees, but usage is more or less the same

Comment: @jabaa or call `std::list::sort`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, I didn't know about it. Of course, that's a far better option.

Comment: @jabaa, yes, i have to call std::list::sort...

Comment: @jabaa using a `std::vector` in the first place would be the better option ;). I am not aware of what a `std::list` does better than a `std::vector`, especially with considerably small number of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::list` has no RandomAccessIterator, hence you cannot use `std::sort`, though there is `std::list::sort` that takes a custom predicate. Your predicate should compare the indices of to be compared elements in `sortRule`:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string data1{"data1"};
    std::string data2{"data2"};
    std::string data3{"data3"};

    std::list<std::string> list = {data2, data2, data2, data3, data3, data1, data1};
    std::list<std::string> sortRule = {data1, data2, data3};
    list.sort([&sortRule](const auto& a,const auto& b){
        auto index_a = std::distance(sortRule.begin(), std::find(sortRule.begin(),sortRule.end(),a));
        auto index_b = std::distance(sortRule.begin(), std::find(sortRule.begin(),sortRule.end(),b));
        return index_a < index_b;
    });
    for (const auto& e : list) std::cout << e << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
data1
data1
data2
data2
data2
data3
data3
```

Though, this is extremely inefficient. Finding the element in the `sortRule` list requires traversing the list, calculating the distance requires traversing the list again. And this is done twice for each single comparison. You could prepare a `std::map<std::string, size_t>` for easier lookup of the index from the string. Also you should consider to use `std::vector` instead of `std::list` for `list`. Having RandomAccessIterators makes sorting much easier.